# No puedo instalar React en mi pc porque la instalacion no se completa

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy tratando de instalar React en mi pc, pero pasa que cuando lo instalo con el comando `npx create-react-app my-app`, al principio esta normal, pero despues se detiene en esta parte:

```
Creating a new React app in D:\Proyectos\Proyectos\React\App\visual-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall D:\Proyectos\Proyectos\React\App\visual-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall D:\Proyectos\Proyectos\React\App\visual-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall D:\Proyectos\Proyectos\React\App\visual-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react@17.0.1
+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-scripts@3.4.4
+ react-dom@17.0.1
added 1591 packages from 744 contributors and audited 1595 packages in 241.438s

73 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Y de ahi no continua ni me deja escribir nada mas. Abro una nueva consola y trato de entrar a la carpeta donde lo instale y ejecuto el siguiente paso que es `npm start` pero solo me aparece esto:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-02T04_20_27_016Z-debug.log
```

Por cierto asi esta mi package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-titulo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  }
}
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar esto, o cual puede ser mi problema?

Comment: Con que se detiene, ¿te refieres a que nunca termina el script de inicio de tu app? ¿puedes compartir el log completo de cuando tratas de crear tu app? ¿qué versión de node/npm/create-react-app estás usando? ¿en qué os?

Comment: arriba esta todo lo que me aparece, mi version de node es v14.12.0 y de npm es 6.14.8. La version de react que uso es la ultima 17.0.1. Estoy en Windows 10

Comment: ¿has probado con [las otras formas](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app) de crear una app? Usando `npm init react-app my-app` o `yarn create react-app my-app`

Answer (score 0):

Solo es necesario agregar a tu fichero `package.json` esto:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node tu-script-main.js"
  },
```

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta puede ser la solución al problema, es mejor dar respuestas que además del código, contengan una explicación. Ver [answer]